# Is there a way to add a person who killed you as a friend?

Tags: fortnite-battle-royale

While playing Fortnite Battle Royale, I have seen many good players that kill me, and I always want to add them as a friend, so they could carry me. Most of these people are already friends with my friends on Fortnite. Is there a way to add a player as a friend in game if they kill you? (Not in LTM's just Squads, Duos and Solo.)

Answer (score 6):

## Not in game.

Once a player kills you the game will show you their name, so once you return to the lobby you can add them through the friends feature.